# What .NET Framework versions support the runtime enhancements for Span<T>?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I understand `Span<T>` can be used on the .NET Framework as a Nuget package. [There have been JIT upgrades to .NET Core to improve performance of `Span<T>` to nearly standard array performance.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/16/ryujit-just-in-time-compiler-optimization-enhancements/)

What .NET Framework versions support these runtime enhancements to the performance of `Span<T>`?

Comment: Nothing special is needed in CLR nor the jitter.  You have to abide by what the Nuget package wants, you can turn the clock back up to 6 years, back to .NET 4.5.  Going back further might work but voids the warranty.

Comment: @HansPassant There have been some optimizations, as I've quoted in my response. Without the optimizations it is less fast but still works correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They haven't until .NET 4.7.1 . Taken from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/16/ryujit-just-in-time-compiler-optimization-enhancements/):

> Note: The changes described here landed after the release fork for .NET Core 2.0 was created, so they are available in daily preview builds but not the released 2.0 bits. Similarly, **these changes landed after the fork for .NET Framework 4.7.1 was created**. The changes to struct argument passing and block layout, which are purely JIT changes, will automatically propagate to subsequent .NET Framework releases with the new JIT bits (the RyuJIT sources are shared between .NET Core and .NET Framework); the other changes depend on their runtime components to propagate to .NET Framework.

and then

> **Improvements for Span**
>
> Some of our work was motivated by the introduction of Span, so that it and similar types could better deliver on their performance promises.
>
> One such change was #10910, which made the JIT recognize the Item property getters of Span and ReadOnlySpan as intrinsics

Comment: That seems to answer it for now. If updated answers arrive in the future I might move the accept checkmark over.

Comment: @boot4life No infos found about .NET 4.7.2 ... But in the [release note documents](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/dotnet472-changes.md) they haven't written anything about it.

Answer (score 12):

It's unlikely that "fast span" support will appear in a .NET Framework version anytime soon -- and certainly it's not there in 4.7.2 (or earlier versions) and is not in the plans for 4.8 -- see for instance [this discussion thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/770).

Comment: Wow, didn't realize that .NET Framework 5.0 is basically not in the plans at all. Thanks for the link. It will be very interesting to see how .Net Core 3.0 maps to people's needs.

Comment: For more on what's in store in .Net Core 3.0, at least from a winforms/wpf standpoint, please check out [Are your Windows Forms and WPF applications ready for .NET Core 3.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/08/08/are-your-windows-forms-and-wpf-applications-ready-for-net-core-3-0/)